# UIView drawRect() : fill everything except polygon

Tags: objective-c, ios, polygon, quartz-2d, drawrect

I need to fill my UIView in drawRect() method with 'reverted polygon' - everything in view is filled with some color except polygon itself.

I've got this code to draw a simple polygon:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
for(int i = 0; i < corners.count; ++i)  
{
    CGPoint cur = [self cornerAt:i], next = [self cornerAt:(i + 1) % corners.count];
    if(i == 0)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cur.x, cur.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, next.x, next.y);
}
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

I found a similar question, but in C#, not Obj-C : [c# fill everything but GraphicsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935644/c-sharp-fill-everything-but-graphicspath)

Comment: You can fill your entire view with your fill color and than draw your polygon over it using clear color

Comment: try the same like in the C# code: CGContextAddRect(context,self.bounds) before CGContextClosePath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the fastest way is to set a clip:

```
// create your path as posted
// but don't fill it (remove the last line)

CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);
CGContextEOClip(context);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

Both the other answers suggest to first fill a rect, then draw the shape with clear color on top. Both omit the necessary blend mode. Here's a working version:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

// create and fill your path as posted
```

**Edit:** Both approaches require the `backgroundColor` to be the `clearColor` and `opaque` to be set to NO.

**Second Edit:** The original question was about Core Graphics. Of course there are other ways of masking part of a view. Most notably `CALayer`'s `mask` property.

You can set this property to an instance of a CAPathLayer that contains your clip path to create a stencil effect.

Comment: Thanks, it works! First solution is better, because it doesn't crop the whole view and gives a possibility to draw something else inside cropped polygon.  Also, it works with `opaque` set to `YES` somehow. :)

Comment: @dreamzor Glad I could help. I wouldn't rely on fact that it worked for you with `opaque=YES`, though.

Comment: It's been a while, but now I've found that this way is way too slow. Can it be done another way, using CALayer or something? It doesn't seem like a really hard painting job...

Answer (score 0):

in drawRect u can set the background color of ur view with the color u want

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIcolor redColor]; //set ur color
```

and then draw a polygon the way u r doing.

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
for(int i = 0; i < corners.count; ++i)  
{
    CGPoint cur = [self cornerAt:i], next = [self cornerAt:(i + 1) % corners.count];
    if(i == 0)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cur.x, cur.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, next.x, next.y);
}
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

hope it helps.. happy coding :)

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, @Resh32 had a similar idea too

Comment: You should not set the backgroundColor from within `drawRect`. Also, your approach does not render a transparent shape.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new CGLayer, fill it with your outside color, then draw your polygon using a clear color.

```
layer1 = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.bounds.size, NULL);
context1 = CGLayerGetContext(layer1);

[... fill entire layer ...]

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(self.context1, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);

[... draw your polygon ...]

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, layer1);
```

Comment: What do you need the CGLayer for? Seems unnecessary overhead to me.

Comment: Also, drawing with clear color using default blend mode (porter-duff over) is a no-op.

Comment: The CGLayer would be needed if the main context already have other elements drawn on it (I don't know the remaining parts of the app).

Comment: "The main context" is cleared directly before `drawRect:` is called (on iOS, where Core Animation is the only view compositing engine). On Mac OS without `setWantsLayer:` you would be right.

Comment: Right, but since we do not see the beginning of the code in the original question, we cannot simply assume that there is none. For example, there might be a square drawn, then this transparent inversed polygon would be on top of that, no?

Comment: You are right. From the first sentence of the question I assumed that there's nothing else in the view but it's not explicitly stated.